# How much would 1 million make me per month in interest with the conditions mentioned in the description?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, arithmetic

### Conditions:

1. 1 million is the total initial amount I have.
2. My bank deposits provides me an interest of 4.8% per year after all tax cuts.
3. Whatever interest amount I receive, I want to be able to get 20% more in the next financial year. For example, if I receive 400 per month in the first year, I would want to receive 480 per month in the next year and 576 per month the year after that.
4. This should keep on going and should never stop.

I basically want one part of the million to give me a monthly interest, and the other to keep building the principal such that my monthly interest amount keeps increasing by 20% every year. Please help me solve this.

Comment: You could start by calculating the first two or three years. See if you find a pattern. So this thing of "wanting more interest" - does it mean that the interest rate would grow every year? So that on year $n$, the interest factor is
$$
1.048\times (1.2)^{n-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks for replying... the interest rate from the bank 4.8% would be constant... With that interest rate, the principal should grow such that my monthly interest amount keeps increasing 20% annually...

Comment: Try to form an equation for, for example, how much money is on the bank on year $n+1$, as a function of the same number from year $n$.

Comment: Have you realised that after ten years the monthly interest is about 2477?  Do you really wish that?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe yes I do realize it, but compared to 400 it's quite a lot right... given the rate of inflation, we would still be ahead of the game I guessing... and that was just an example figure... 

Besides I'm currently more interested in the math behind it... The more I try to calculate, it seems less possible... it's getting very confusing after a point... Please help...

Comment: APR or APY ? it matters.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee APR... to make it easier to calculate...

Comment: okay so a rate that doesn't take compounding into account.  what's your pretax cut percentage ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee It actually keeps varying... I didn't want to make it complicated and hence have added a 4.8%... It would be the minimum I would get after the taxes... I thought it would be better to calculate with that, so the amount received won't go below what we calculate... maybe we can remove tax factor completely and calculate with 4.8%?? or will it make a difference if we calculate with the tax??

Comment: Is the interest paid (and compounded) monthly?  Or, in other words, does the bank pay an amount of interest equal to $0.4\%$ of whatever the total value of the deposit is at the end of that month?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes... that was the idea... 0.4% would be deposited at the end of the month... it's compounded annually...

Comment: @lonzaleggiera In my mind, the total amount would be split into two parts... one of them would pay out the 0.4% monthly (of the 4.8% interest that we receive annually) and the other part would keep building the principal amount in such a way that the first part would receive 20% year on year growth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bank deposits only yield $\ 4.8\%\ $ per year interest, then your goal of deriving an income stream therefrom which increases at a rate of $\ 20\%\ $ per year *indefinitely* is not achievable.  Suppose the income you derive from interest in the first year is $\ \epsilon\ $, and let $\ n\ $ be the smallest positive integer such that
$$
\left(\frac{150}{131}\right)^n> \frac{1,000,000}{\epsilon}\ .
$$
Then after $\ n\ $ years, your income stream is required to be $\ 1.2^n\epsilon\ $ per annum, but even if *all* the interest obtained from the bank were devoted to growing the principal, then after $\ n\ $ years the principal would only be $\ 1.048^n\cdot1,000,000\ $, which is *less* than the income of $\ 1.2^n\epsilon\ $ it is required to generate (because $\ 1.2^n\epsilon = \left(\frac{150}{125}\right)^n\epsilon >$$ \left(\frac{131}{125}\right)^n\cdot1,000,000\ $$=1.048^n\cdot1,000,000\ $).